# Pyinstaller, every joblib Parallel call creates a new tkinter window on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, joblib

Here is the code which can reproduce the problem (it is just for reproducing the problem, so what it does is a bit meaningless):

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import tkinter as tk


def f():
    print('func call')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    button = tk.Button(root,
                       command=lambda: Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend='threading')(delayed(f)() for _ in range(1)),
                       text='func')
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

The above code can run perfectly in my IDE, but once I create an executable with Pyinstaller, it bugs.
The command line to create the executable is as below:

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```

The excepted behavior is that, every time when presses the button in the `tkinter` window, a `func call` string should be printed in the terminal. But when I use the executable file to run, every time I press the button, besides the printing in the terminal, a new `tkinter` window is created.

I have also tried to build the executable in Windows with the same command. The executable file runs fine in Windows (No new `tkinter` window is created when pressing the button). Only the MacOS platform has this problem.

How should I fix this?

Here is the platform that I have the problem:

- CPU: ARM64 (M1)
- Python: 3.10
- joblib: 1.1.0
- pyinstaller 5.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` to the code. The fixed version of code is as below:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.freeze_support()

from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import tkinter as tk


def f():
    print('func called')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    button = tk.Button(root,
                       command=lambda: Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend='threading')(delayed(f)() for _ in range(1)),
                       text='func')
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you *rokm* for answering my question on GitHub, here is the URL to *rokm's* answer: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6852#issuecomment-1138269358.

Comment: Please note, `backend='threading'` is required for this solution to work, as mentioned here, https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6852#issuecomment-1198121115.